# Generic Type conversion error on inherited classes

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

im trying to create a an mvc framework to define the workflow of a project im working on.
I created the view and controller classes and was trying to have the ui controller class be generic in order to have a type of uiview assigned to it when inheriting from ui controller:

UIView class

```
    public class UIView
    {
    }
```

UIController class

```
    public class UIController<T> where T : UIView
    {
    }
```

Implementation of UIView class

```
    public class UIMenuView : UIView
    {
    }
```

Implementation of UIController class with UI Menu View

```
    public class MenuController : UIController<UIMenuView>
    {
    }
```

Workflow implementation

```
    void main()
    {
        var menuController = new MenuController();
        SetController(menuController as UIController<UIView>);
    }

    public void SetController(UIController<UIView> controller, bool asRoot = false)
    {
    }
```

The problem is im getting the following error while trying to set the controller:

> Cannot convert type 'MenuController' to 'UI.UIController<UI.UIView>'
> via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion,
> wrapping conversion, or null type conversion [Assembly-CSharp]

Does anybody know what im doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Why not add a type parameter `T` (`where T : UIView`) to `SetController` and change `UIController<UIView>` to `UIController<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

Following picture shows your inheritance hierarchy. Your casting `menuController as UIController<UIView>` is what described with red arrow which is wrong.

[image]

Comment: isnt UIController<UIView> the main parent in my hierarchy?
UIMenuView also inherits from UIView.

Comment: No. Because both `typeof(UIController<UIView>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(UIController<UIMenuView>))` and `typeof(UIController<UIMenuView>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(UIController<UIView>))` return `false`